# TFS31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

We just upgraded our TFS 2013 to TFS 2015. We use VS2015 to communicate with it(we were already using it with our TFS2013). The server was not available during the time our IT made the upgrade.

After the ugprade, everybody started to work again with the server but I was seing it as Offline and I finally decided to remove the server and add it again.

When I add it again(200% sure of all the settings), I get this error:
[image: TFS31002 error]

I finally tried to do the same on our "old" installation of Visual Studio 2013(same computer, same account), and it works. I was at least capable to commit all my changes to the server.
I tried to go on the portal and click on `Open in Visual Studio", and I got another error(TFS400324):
[image: TFS400324 error]

Now I'm trying to regain access to TFS2015 with my VS2015. I can access the web portal.

Here is what I tried after some research:

- Do a Repair of Visual Studio 2015
- Check that I've no weird proxy
- Check that there is no available update(already at VS2015 UPD 1)
- Clear the cache of all my Internet explorer
- Cleared `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\*.*\Cache`
- Run VS2015 in admin
- Disable my antivirus
- Delete registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\*.*\ClientServices\TokenStorage`
- Check that I've no proxy declared in: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*.*\Config\machine.config`
- I did a windows update.
- I ran the command devenv.exe /resetuserdata

Any clue what is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

VS 2013 can connect to TFS 2015, but VS 2015 can't. So the issue is on client side. Try on another client machine to connect TFS 2015 with VS 2015 to check the result.

1. Clean the client cache: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache and C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache. Make sure both 5.0 and 6.0 folder are cleaned.
2. Clean server cache on AT machine: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services_tfs_data, and C:\TfsData\ApplicationTier_fileCache
3. Remove all credentials in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager.
4. Remove TFS server in Team Explorer: go to Manage Connections--Connect to Team Project--Servers, select TFS 2015, remove it and add it.
5. Connect TFS 2015 with it's IP address, not server name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Other people can connect to TFS2015 with VS2015. We also checked that if I log on another computer it also work. So it's really a computer/visual studio issue. 
What do you mean by AT machine? I've done every other things, but I still got the same issue

Comment: AT machine means Application Tier machine. Did you restart your PC?

Comment: Ok, so you mean the machine where TFS is installed??? And yes I rebooted ~4-5 times at least. I will reboot now after cleaning again all your files just to be sure

Comment: We use "Application Tier" because you can have multiple machines running TFS, typically for load balancing or disaster recovery.

Comment: We don't have access directly to this server, and the IT guy in question told us he won't delete the cache because we are able to connect with the same user from another Visual Studio(2013 on local computer or 2015 on another one). I tried everything else you specified, but it didn't change anything

Comment: @J4N, if you user other's credential to connect TFS on your computer, can you access it? Try resetting settings and add-in settings of VS 2015 (devenv /ResetSettings) and (devenv /ResetSkipPkgs), and rebuilding all templates (devenv /setup).

Comment: @Cece-MSFT others users logged on my computer have the same issue: Not working with VS2015, working with VS2013. If I use my credentials on another computer, both work. I tried all your commands, but they doesn't change anything

Comment: I suggest you compare the software of your computer with others, to see whether there is some software block your VS 2015 to communicate with TFS.

Comment: Well, I think I've at least 30 differents applications than my colleagues. I reinstalled the whole computer(with the same software) and now it works fine. The issue is definitely a VS2015 issue.

Comment: Sorry to hear you have such experience. It's hard to say which software blocks the VS 2015 to communicate with TFS, or the VS 2015 itself can't work on your computer, as the PC environment can't be reproduced on our side. If the issue happens again, you can consider opening a support ticket at webisite: https://www.visualstudio.com/support/support-overview-vs

Answer (score 0):

This answer will not please to anybody coming here for an answer, but I had to format my computer and do a whole clean install on it.

Answer (score 0):

A little trick might help.
Change port 8080 to another port. I've changed to port 5000
I hope to be useful.